# access protected variable - complicated situation with inheritance and sub-classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, protected, derived-class, subclassing

Hmm... I'm trying to break down my problem...
There is a library with some classes that do almost what I want. I can't change classes of the library so I want to derive them and change what I need.
In this case there is a derived class in the library with two subclasses. Now I derive the class and the subclasses.
In the second sub-class there is a virtual method witch modifies a protected variable from the first sub-class.
I want to override the virtual method with a new virtual method which calls the old virtual wethod an then modify the protected variable again.

Why am I getting the error in mySubClass2 while accessing fResponse?

How can I solve my problem?

```cpp
class libraryClass : pulic someLibraryBaseClass {
protected:
  libraryClass::librarySubClass2 lookUpFunction(int ID) {
    //some magic to find the obj
    return obj;
  }

public:
  class librarySubClass2;
  class librarySubClass1 {
  public:

    librarySubClass1(libraryClass baseObj) {
      myBaseObj = baseObj;
    }

    void someCallingFunction(int ID) {
      libraryClass::librarySubClass2 obj = myBaseObj->lookUpFunction(ID)
      obj->someHandleFunction(this)
      cout << fResponse;
    }
  protected:
    friend class librarySubClass2;
    unsigned char fResponse[200];
  private:
    libraryClass myBaseObj;
  };
  class librarySubClass2 {
  protected:
    virtual void someHandleFunction(libraryClass::librarySubClass1* obj) {
      snprintf((char*)obj->fResponse, sizeof obj->fResponse, "Some Text...\r\n"
    }
  };
};


class myDerivedClass : public libraryClass {
public:
  class mySubClass2 : public libraryClass::librarySubClass2;
  class mySubClass1 : public libraryClass::librarySubClass1 {
  protected:
    friend class mySubClass2;
  };

  class mySubClass2 : public libraryClass::librarySubClass2 {
  protected:
    virtual void someHandleFunction(libraryClass::librarySubClass1* obj) {
      libraryClass:librarySubClass2::someHandleFuntion(obj);
      snprintf((char*)obj->fResponse, sizeof obj->fResponse, "Add some more Text...\r\n"
    }
  };
};
```

Edit: Forgot * in Method of mySubClass2

Possible solution:

```
  class mySubClass2 : public libraryClass::librarySubClass2 {
  protected:
    virtual void someHandleFunction(libraryClass::librarySubClass1* obj) {
      libraryClass:librarySubClass2::someHandleFuntion(obj);
      myDerivedClass::mySubClass1* nowMyObj = (myDerivedClass::mySubClass*) obj;
      snprintf((char*)nowMyObj->fResponse, sizeof nowMyObj->fResponse, "Add some more Text...\r\n"
    }
  };
```

Comment: I'd start with putting parentheses around `obj->fResponse`: `sizeof(obj->fResponse)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I derive the class and the subclasses.

In your example code, you're only deriving the main class and not the subclass. You have to inherit also the subclass:

```
class libraryClass : pulic someLibraryBaseClass 
{
  class librarySubClass1 : public someLibraryBaseClass::someLibrarySubClass1 { };

  // ....
};
```

But that can be done only if the subclass is accessible (protected/public).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you wonder why you can't access `obj->fResponse` in

```
void mySubClass2::someHandleFunction(libraryClass::librarySubClass1 obj) { ... }
```

Well, `obj` is of type `librarySubClass1` which inherits its share of `fResponse` from the common ancestor. However, that is the share of a relative of `mySubClass2`, not yours as you are `mySubClass2`! You can only access the `fResponse` member of objects which are known to be of type `mySubClass` which actually happens to be known to be not the case for a `librarySubClass1` object.

Getting access to `librarySubClass::fResponse` is as if you got free access to your uncle's inheritance from your grandparents. Unless you have a very unusual family sharing its wealth freely among all family members, you probably won't have access to your uncle's inheritance either.

Comment: Hmm... I think you are right. I fiddled around a Little bit and changed the method of mySubClass2. I casted the library obj to mySubClass Obj.
myDerivedClass::mySubClass1* noMyObj = (myDerivedClass::mySubClass1*) obj

Answer (score 0):

Because fResponse in mySubClass2 is treated as protected and at that point it is outside of libraryClass, it only worked on librarySubClass2 because it is inside libraryClass.